# Clicar em uma div Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Preciso clicar no botão 'AO VIVO AGORA' na página 'https://www.academiadasapostasbrasil.com/'. Fiz o seguinte script, mas está dando um erro, could not be scrolled into view. Abaixo está o código.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.academiadasapostasbrasil.com/'

web_r = requests.get(url)
web_soup = BeautifulSoup(web_r.text, 'html.parser')

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

elemento = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="fh_live_tab"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Duas coisas:

1. Primeiro é necessário que você utilize um scroll pra que pagina role
   até onde aparece o botão que vc deseja clickar.

   `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, num)")`

em num vc coloca o número de pixel que vc quer que a página role exemplo:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 320)")
```

2. Segundo a **tag** html e o **id** estavam incorretos a **tag** correta é `a` e o
   **id** correto é  `show_tab3`

   `elemento = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="show_tab3"]').click()`

Comment: Muito obrigado, Juan Caio. Deu certo, entretanto agora estou com outro problema. Queria que o código HTML após o click do botão fosse enviado para mim. Entretanto quando eu retorno o HTML, apenas me é retornado o HTML antigo, sem o click do botão. Sabe me dizer alguma alternativa pra conseguir o HTML que está após clicar no botao 'AO VIVO AGORA'? Obrigado.

Comment: Pra lhe ajudar melhor, como vc está retornando esse html?

Comment: Estou usando o seguinte comando para retornar o html. html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
sel_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

Comment: Vc pode fazer o seguinte:

`content = driver.page_source`

`soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')`

Ai vc pode pegar a div correta:

`dados = soup.find("div", attrs={"id":"fh_live_tab"})`

E depois se quiser pode pegar a tabela:

`tabela = dados.find('table', attrs={"class":"competition-today dskt"})`

Comment: Juan, a variável dados está vindo sem o conteúdo dentro. Dessa forma, a tabela retorna None. [<div class="boxed tabcontent games_wrapper" id="fh_live_tab" style="opacity: 0.911494; display: block;"><div id="loader-wrapper" style="height: 80px; width: 642px;"><div class="load-overlay" style="width: 642px; height: 80px;"><div class="ajax-loading big"></div></div></div></div>]

Comment: Heuller olhe esse código [aqui](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PhPZGDeH0u15X1pv604Lq83h76wCvF-_?usp=sharing) que realizei como teste e compare com o seu código.

Comment: Juan, não sei porque, mas está me retornando None a tabela. Posso entrar em contato com você via alguma rede social?

Comment: Pode falar comigo la no Linkedin.